# Laravel where clause returns only one db entry

Tags: laravel, database

I'm trying to return multiple lines from my DB using Laravel. The lines of the DB are as following:

```
+----+--------------------+-----------+--------------+--------+---------+
| id | drank              | categorie | besteld_door | aantal | status  |
+----+--------------------+-----------+--------------+--------+---------+
|  1 | Cola               | Frisdrank | Pieter       |      1 | Besteld |
|  2 | Grolsch            | Bier      | Henk         |      1 | Besteld |
|  3 | Cabernet Sauvignon | Wijn      | Mark         |      3 | Besteld |
|  4 | Heineken           | Bier      | Freek        |      1 | Besteld |
|  5 | Heineken           | Bier      | Pieter       |      1 | Besteld |
+----+--------------------+-----------+--------------+--------+---------+
```

I'm trying to get all lines where the column 'besteld_door' is 'Pieter', however my Laravel code (see below) is only returning the first entry..

```
$user = 'Pieter';
$bestelling = Drink::where('besteld_door', $user)->value('drank'); // --> returns 'Cola'
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Wrong method; use `->pluck('drank')`. `->value()` returns the first value only.

Comment: Side comment, but you probably want your `besteld_door` (ordered_by) column to contain a `user_id`, instead of a name. `Pieter` is not unique; you will get cross-contamination if you use that for a large data set  (unless that table is just a representation, in which case, disregard)

Comment: Thank you very much @TimLewis, also for the side comment! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the value of "drank" use `pluck()`

```
$bestelling = Drink::where('besteld_door', $user)->pluck('drank');
//if you want the array use ->toArray()
$bestellingArray = $bestelling->toArray();
```

If you want a collection of the models and not just the column "drank" use `get()`

```
$bestelling = Drink::where('besteld_door', $user)->get();
//you can then loop the results
foreach ($bestelling as $drink) {
    echo $drink->drank;
}
```